# Run different parts of the code in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I don't know how can I ask this question properly. Hope you will understand what I mean. I have a code in Matlab, and I've different processes. For example, if I use some tye of image (for example, *.bmp) I *have to run some code in Matlab and if I have another type of image* (*.jpg) I want to run another part of the code.

But, what I want to do is that at the beginning of the code Matlab asks 'what kind of image?' (for example, with the comand 'disp), and then I would write 'bmp' or 'jpg' and run the related code. I prefer not using a loop, just 'write' the word, and it could identify the process.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use functional, structured programming:

```
function [some output args] = someFunction([some input args])

    answer = [ask question here]

    switch lower(answer)
        case 'bmp'
            [some (other) output args] = bmpfunction([some (other) input args]);
        case 'jpg'
            [some (other) output args] = jpgfunction([some (other) input args]);
        otherwise
            error('Unsupported image format.');
    end

end

function [some output args] = bmpfunction([some input args])
    ...
    [bmp operations]
    ...
end

function [some output args] = jpgfunction([some input args])
    ...
    [jpg operations]
    ...
end
```

Put this all in a single file. Then you can call the function in Matlab by typing

```
someFunction([some input args])
```

where of course, `[some input args]` etc. should be replaced everywhere with actually useful entities :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the following:

```
prompt = "What type of image? "
strResponse = input(prompt, 's')

switch strResponse
...
```

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way to do this would be working object oriented. Then you can use overloading of functions - and save the switch statement completely.

like this:

```
classdef JpegImage    
    methods
        function myFunction(obj)
            ...
            jpegfunction
        end
    end
end

classdef BmpImage    
    methods
        function myFunction(obj)
            ...
            bmpfunction
        end
    end
end
```

In your code you can then use `myFunction(x)` without checking what kind x is.